# Sending/Recieving an binary_oarchive over asio tcp stream with libboost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-serialization

I'm coding for a robot which i need to have all robot's data in my computer while it's running for debug purposes. I have written a class named debug provider which has this responsibility. here is the code i written for this class:

```
void
DebugProvider::doWork()
{
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), 10001);
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, endpoint);

        tcp::iostream stream;
        boost::system::error_code error;
        acceptor.accept(*stream.rdbuf(), error);
        if(!error)
        {
                boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(stream);
                oa << dataProvider;
        }
        usleep(50);
}
```

doWork method is called every 50us in a boost::thread, and DataProvider contains all the data in the robot (like camera image, joints position, etc.).

I also wrote a simple client which gets the data from robot and shows camera image in my laptop. (since I'm testing the code, it gets the data once).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DataProvider dp;
    tcp::iostream stream("10.1.1.1", "10001");
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(stream);
    ia >> dp;

    Mat mat = dp.getCameraImage();
    imshow("camera", mat);
    waitKey();

   return 0;
}
```

My problem is after running the program both in robot and computer. both programs throw an stream_error.

I tried with telnet to get data from the server and everything works fine but with boost::asio::ip::tcp the described error throws.